# Is there a way I can set a math function as a parameter for another function

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, numpy, math

For example, let's say you want to create a function that yields double the function at a certain value, like this:

```
def doubler(f(x),n):
    return 2*f(n)
```

Example:

```
doubler(2*x,1)
```

would yield `4 (2*(2*1))`

The reason I want to do this is because I'm creating a module that allows someone to solve various problems, such as normalizing a wave function of a system (so the function of `x` will be a parameter, i.e input)

Comment: You can do it using lambdas. Python is a functional language with support of higher order functions.

Comment: @Ezio Has nothing to do with lambda. It can be done using any function.

Comment: yes you are right.

Check this if it helps: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/passing-function-as-an-argument-in-python/

Comment: What have **YOU** tried / researched so far? Share **YOUR** code / ideas / findings.

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer; this tells others that your issue is resolved and helps them find the correct answer more easily.

Comment: Also, I have just edited my answer; see if that helps you.

Answer (score 4):

You can, but you need to pass in an actual function. `lambda` will create a single-use function that you can pass in to `doubler`.

```
def doubler(func, x):
    return func(x)*2

print(doubler(lambda x: x*2, 2))
# Prints 8
```

Alternatively, you can pass in a named function.

```
def doubler(func, x):
    return func(x)*2

def f(x):
    return x*2

print(doubler(f, 2))
# Still prints 8
```

EDIT: Another, **NOT RECOMMENDED**, way is using `eval`.

Note that this requires inputting a string, and that if you allow for user input, you'll likely want to filter the input to make sure they can't run Python code.

```py
def doubler(func,n):
    x = n
    return 2*eval(func)

print(doubler("x**2", 3))
# Prints 18
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are aiming for the following:

```
def doubler(f):
    def inner(n):
        return 2 * f(n)
    return inner

def square(n):
    return n**2

>>> double_square = doubler(square)
>>> double_square(3)
18
>>> double_square(4)
32
```

Note that the `doubler` function returns a function itself which encapsulates the desired behaviour.
Alternatively, closer to what you describe, you can pass both function and parameter:

```
def doubler(f, x):
    return 2 * f(x)

>>> doubler(square, 3)
18
>>> doubler(square, 4)
32
```

But the benefit of this is not immediately obvious, as you could just pass `square(3)` or `square(4)` as an argument to a much simpler function.

Comment: Partial application in python! Awesome.

Comment: Also works as `def doubler(f): return (lambda n: 2 * f(n))`

Comment: Is there a way I can do this where the user doesn't have to define an independent function?

So instead of 

def square(): ...

They would just put doubler(x**2)

Comment: You can't just put in an expression that would get evaluated, losing the purpose. YOu would have to use an anonymous function (`lambda`): `double_square = doubler(lambda x: x**2)`